# Can WordPress send automatic email if the user did not login for 15 days?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to work on a project, there is something I could not find a way to do it. 
I'll be using BuddyPress, when the user logins in, he must login at least one time each 15 days. 
If the user did not login again for 15 days, an automatic email will be sent to him, as notification.

Any idea? 
Thank you

Comment: Write a cronjob that queries the user database and checks the date of the last login. If that is > X days, send a mail via wp_mail() or whatever you like. Just an idea.

Comment: Try: https://github.com/imath/bp-wake-up-sleepers

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try both ways and get back to you :)